# Source of change in timestamp-format in default solr implementation

Tags: solr, velocity, solritas

In Solr Index the format of my date-field is "2014-06-27T10:25:56.204Z" as expected. I can see this when calling: /solr/admin/luke?wt=xslt&tr=luke.xsl&fl=description&numTerms=200&docId=2

Anyhow the format of my date-field coming from Solritas (the default ResponseWriter) is Fri Jun 27 10:25:56 CEST 2014.

I can't find the location, where this transformation happens in order to change the format of the date-field according to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the source of format change yet, but I know how to change the format anyhow:

```
     #set($myDate = $doc.getFieldValue('myDate'))
     $date.format("d. MMM. yyyy, h:mm",$myDate)
```